# How to get Function to Access Varibles in Another Function

Tags: python, function, oop, ros

I have multiple functions. One function (estimation) calls on the variables of the other(callback) in order to perform a calculation. However, there are a couple of issues.

1. It seems like the variables aren't getting passed, and ...
2. It seems like the function(estimation) never gets called to run, and I don't know why.

What I want is to have the estimate result print out, but nothing is being printed.

If someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

EX:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import math
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
import numpy as np
from rclpy.qos import qos_profile_sensor_data

class S_E(Node):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__('s_e')
        self.sub = self.create_subscription(Imu, '/imu', self.callback, qos_profile=qos_profile_sensor_data)

   def callback(self, msg):

       quat        = self.quat     = msg.orientation       # x,y,z
       a_rate      = self.a_rate   = msg.angular_velocity  # x,y,z
       
       return quat, a_rate


   def estimation(self):
       print("Hello")

       quat, a_rate  = callback()
       estimate      =  (0.5 * a_rate)  * quat
       print(estimate)




def main(args=None):
   rclpy.init(args=args)  # initialize ROS2 Library
   s_e = S_E()  # make an object of class 
   try:
       while (1):
           rclpy.spin(s_e)
   except Exception as e:
       print("Exception: {}".format(e))
   

   rclpy.spin(s_e)
   
   rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: You are going to need to elaborate on *exactly* what is going wrong.

Comment: Note, in `estimation` you call `callback()`, but that isn't defined in that scope... it's totally unclear what you expect any of this to do.

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll update it. But to answer your question here, nothing is printing. I want estimate to print, but I get nothing.

Comment: Right, well, you haven't provided a [mcve]. You are using some library, but at the very least oyu need to describe what you expect that library to do, why do you *expect* `.estimation` to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the estimation function on your object. You would do that by doing something like this

```
s_e = S_E()
s_e.estimation()
```

Comment: Another question, I was able to get the function called. However, I get an error: quat, a_rate  = callback(), as it says the name 'callback' isn't defined- so I can't access the variables. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Anytime you want to call a function that is part of a class the only way to "access" it is to call it with an object of that class. And if you are calling it from within a function of that class then the object is self. In you case you would do ```self.callback()```